# any wrong on this DELETE procedure. can we write like this or is there any better way to write same proc

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here we are just deleting the records from master and child table prior to 90days history records. Assume that tables have more than 20k records are there to delete. And here I put commit for each 5k records. Please let me know if I am wrong here?

```
create or replace Procedure PURGE_CLE_ALL_STATUS  ( days_in IN number ) 
IS 

       reccount  NUMBER  := 0;

       CURSOR del_record_cur IS

    SELECT EXCEPTIONID   FROM   EXCEPTIONREC
         WHERE  trunc(TIME_STAMP) < trunc(sysdate - days_in );


BEGIN
       FOR rec IN del_record_cur LOOP

      delete from EXCEPTIONRECALTKEY   -- child table 
          where EXCEPTIONID =rec.EXCEPTIONID ;

      delete from EXCEPTIONREC -- master table
          where EXCEPTIONID =rec.EXCEPTIONID;  


         reccount := reccount + 1;

         IF (reccount >= 1000) THEN
           COMMIT;
           count := 0;
         END IF;
       commit;
       END LOOP;
       COMMIT;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Deleted ' || total || ' records from <OWNER>.<TABLE_NAME>.');
END;
/
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having with it?

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking whether the code can be made more efficient, the most efficient approach is always to do things in SQL

```
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM EXCEPTIONRECALTKEY child
   WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                   FROM EXCEPTIONREC parent
                  WHERE child.EXCEPTIONID = parent.EXCEPTIONID 
                    AND parent.timestamp <= trunc(sysdate - days_in ) );
  DELETE FROM EXCEPTIONREC 
   WHERE timestamp <= trunc(sysdate - days_in );
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But how can i apply Commit after every 5k records ?

Comment: @user1396473 - Why do you want to commit every 5000 rows?  That only slows your process down and causes it to consume more resources on the database.

Comment: Committing every 5000 records also makes it a little hazy if you need to recover.  Such incremental DML was a good idea in, say, Oracle 8, but in 10g?  11g?  No, you are just making life difficult (and slow) for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a foreign key defined from EXCEPTIONRECALTKEY to EXCEPTIONREC  then you can issue a delete against an inline view that joins the two tables, specifying a WHERE clause against the parent table and causing records to be deleted from the child table.

Thus:

```
BEGIN
  delete from (
    select
      p.EXCEPTIONID p_EXCEPTIONID,
      c.EXCEPTIONID c_EXCEPTIONID,
      c.TIME_STAMP  c_TIME_STAMP
    from
      EXCEPTIONREC       p,
      EXCEPTIONRECALTKEY c
    where
      p.EXCEPTIONID = c.EXCEPTIONID and
      c.TIMESTMAP < trunc(sysdate - days_in ));

  delete from
    EXCEPTIONREC
  where
    TIMESTMAP < trunc(sysdate - days_in );  
end;
/
```

Comment: I need to give commit after every 5k records deleted, Could you please le tme know how to write like that. Thanks for your great help here.